# How to create zones in mongodb

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

i have deployed a shard cluster with 2 shard replica sets and i want shardA replica set primary in one zone and secondaries in another zone same way shardB replica set primary in one zone and secondaries are in another zone please help me how to create zone using which command i can create this.

Comment: Have a look at [Manage Shard Zones](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-shard-zone/)

Comment: At the "old times" term was "Tag aware sharing", now it's more like https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/zone-sharding/

Comment: but in webside documentation we have how to shard zones not replicas